# Como Retirar Cabeçalho e Rodapé com @media print CSS?

Tags: css

Estou utilizando o `@media print{}` do CSS para personalizar a página na hora de imprimir, porém não estou conseguindo retirar o rodapé e cabeçalho criado pelo **próprio navegador**.

Sei que dá para retirar pelas configurações do `Browser`, mas não sei como retirar via código com `CSS` ou através do javascript?

Segue abaixo o que tentei:

```
header { display: none !important; } 
footer { display: none !important; }
```

Comment: header {
        display: none !important;
    } 

    footer {
        display: none !important;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paula, tente isso no seu @media print:

```
@page{size: auto;}
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigada :D

Answer (score 4):

No caso cabeçalho e rodapé do navegador sei que é possível nas configurações:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas vi uma resposta no `SO` dizendo que esse `css` surtiria efeito:

```
@page 
    {
        size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
        margin: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
    }
```

Fonte:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228088/remove-header-and-footer-from-window-print

Caso esteja falando de um Header ou footer criado por você:

Você pode fazer isso utilizando `display`: `none`;

A propriedade CSS `display` especifica o tipo de caixa de renderização usada por um elemento.

Display com valor `none`:
Desabilita a exibição do elemento (sem afetar o layout); todos os elementos filhos também tem sua exibição desabilitada.

```css
@media print{
   #noprint{
       display:none;
   }
}

@page{
  size: auto;
  margin: 0mm;
}
```

```html
<div id="noprint">
    Elemento que será ocultado na impressão...
</div>
```

Comment: Estou utilizando o media=print com o display:none para esconder vários elementos mas o cabeçalho e o Rodapé são criados sozinhos, quando peço para visualizar a página de impressão ele coloca a data em cima e embaixo de cada página um link e quando desativo no Browser a opção: "Cabeçalho e Rodapé" aí desaparece, mas gostaria de tirar via código CSS com o media=print. estou utilizando o Chrome como navegador

Comment: não são elementos da minha página, o browser que cria esse Cabeçalho e Rodapé quando se faz qualquer impressão, se pedir para imprimir está página por exemplo vai aparecer um cabeçalho com a data e um rodapé com o link desta página em todas as páginas criado pelo browser e é isto que eu preciso retirar

Comment: Vaaaaaaaaaaaaaleeeu @Caique Romero, ajudou demais

Answer (score 1):

Cria uma classe dentro de um `@media print` e coloque essa classe em todos os elementos que você deseja excluir na hora da impressão.

```
@media print {

    .no-print{
       display: none;
    }

}

<a href="#" class="no-print"> Link do Rodapé </a>
```